# Calculating time difference between 2 dates in minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a field of time Timestamp in my MySQL database which is mapped to a `DATE` datatype in my bean. Now I want a query by which I can fetch all records in the database for which the difference between the current timestamp and the one stored in the database is > 20 minutes.

How can I do it?

**What i want is:**

```
SELECT * FROM MyTab T WHERE T.runTime - now > 20 minutes
```

Are there any MySQL functions for this, or any way to do this in SQL?

Comment: Are you really trying to select records whose timestamp is at least 20 minutes in the future?  Because that's what the condition in your query says.

Answer (score 183):

If you have MySql version **above 5.6** you could use [TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) something like

```
select * from MyTab T where
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,T.runTime,NOW()) > 20
```

Comment: select * from MyTab T where
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,T.runTime,NOW()) > 20  (T.runTime is the coulmn of MyTab table)

Comment: it doesn't include the second only show the difference of minute

Comment: My suplyed MySql doesn't have that, is version 5.5 I had to use TIMEDIFF instead.

Answer (score 31):

MySql version >=5.6

I am using below code for today and database date.

**`TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,T.runTime,NOW()) > 20`**

[According to the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), the first argument can be any of the following:

```
MICROSECOND
SECOND
MINUTE
HOUR
DAY
WEEK
MONTH
QUARTER
YEAR
```

Comment: Because of the %60 you are ignoring differences larger than one hour...

Comment: @SparK is correct, remove the %60, else for 90 minutes you'll only get 30.

Comment: Not everybody has MySql 5.6 it is a new VERSION feature...

Comment: @SergioAbreu, mysql version added in answer.

Answer (score 29):

```
ROUND(time_to_sec((TIMEDIFF(NOW(), "2015-06-10 20:15:00"))) / 60);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this one:

```
select * from MyTab T where date_add(T.runTime, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) < NOW()
```

NOTE: this should work if you're using MySQL DateTime format. If you're using Unix Timestamp (integer), then it would be even easier:

```
select * from MyTab T where UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - T.runTime > 20*60
```

UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function returns you current unix timestamp.

Comment: I don't know is MySQL's optimizer is smart enough to do this by itself, but on general principle I'd rewrite the first condition as `T.runTime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTES)`.

Comment: why do you think the rewritten condition is faster than the initial one?

Comment: It might not be, if MySQL is smart enough, but in general, if you have an index on `t.col`, then `t.col < func(const)` ought to be faster than `invfunc(t.col) < const` because the DB can precalculate the right hand side and use the index.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen This fails for me if I use `MINUTES`, but works if I use `MINUTE`.  Per [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) `MINUTE` is expected by `DATE_ADD` and `DATE_SUB` in ver 5.5.  Does `MINUTES` work in other versions?

Comment: @Andrew: You're right, it should be `INTERVAL 20 MINUTE`.  I can't edit my comment any more to fix it, but I can (and just did) edit the answer.

Comment: Not sure if they've corrected it yet, but when I last used `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` it was only 32 bit (signed) - that  meant it would not operate more than 68 yrs either side of 1970 (1902 to 2038) - may not be a problem just now, but then the millenium bug wasn't a problem in the 1980s

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: 
`SELECT *  FROM MyTab T   WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() > T.runTime + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE;`

The CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() is a function and returns the current date and time. This function works From MySQL 4.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySql version prior than 5.6 you don't have TIMESTAMPDIFF. So,I wrote my own MySql function to do this. Accets %i or %m for minutes and %h for hours. You can extend it.

Example of usage:

```
 SELECT MYTSDIFF('2001-01-01 10:44:32', '2001-01-01 09:50:00', '%h')
```

Here goes the function. Enjoy:

```
 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS MYTSDIFF;

 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE FUNCTION `MYTSDIFF`( date1 timestamp, date2 timestamp, fmt varchar(20))
 returns varchar(20) DETERMINISTIC

 BEGIN

     declare secs smallint(2);
     declare mins smallint(2);
     declare hours int;
     declare total real default 0;
     declare str_total varchar(20);

     if date1 > DATE_ADD( date2, interval 30 day) then
       return '999999.999'; /* OUT OF RANGE TIMEDIFF */
     end if;

     select cast( time_format( timediff(date1, date2), '%s') as signed) into secs;
     select cast( time_format( timediff(date1, date2), '%i') as signed) into mins;
     select cast( time_format( timediff(date1, date2), '%H') as signed) into hours;

     set total = hours * 3600 + mins * 60 + secs;  

     set fmt = LOWER( fmt);

     if fmt = '%m' or fmt = '%i' then
       set total = total / 60;
     elseif fmt = '%h' then
       set total = total / 3600;
     else
       /* Do nothing, %s is the default: */
       set total = total + 0;
     end if;

     select cast( total as char(20)) into str_total;

     return str_total;

 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```