# Difference between two datetime entries

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, datediff

```
SELECT ETA,STA FROM `Schedule` WHERE `Num`="5567";
```

> `2013-08-26 18:37:00    2013-08-26 18:30:00`

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ETA,STA) FROM `Schedule` WHERE `Num`="5567";
```

> `0`

Why the result is 0 instead of 7 (i.e. minutes)?

Comment: The [manual of MySQL and DATEDIFF says it returns the difference in days](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATEDIFF will give result in days.

```
SELECT HOUR (ETA - STA) FROM `Schedule` WHERE `Num`="5567";
```

An alternative for hour difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `TIME_TO_SEC` MySQL function.

**Sample**

```
SELECT (TIME_TO_SEC(ETA) - TIME_TO_SEC(STA))/60 AS `minutes`
```

Comment: @KlausosKlausos you want to save this fields means.??? are you storing this into other table..?

Answer (score 0):

Use TIMEDIFF function

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(ETA,STA) FROM `Schedule` WHERE `Num`="5567";
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this thread on how to calculate the difference in munites: [Calculating time difference between 2 dates in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636599/calculating-time-difference-between-2-dates-in-minutes)

`DATEDIFF` will return the difference in days!

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):
DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
    -> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT (TIMEDIFF(ETA,STA)) FROM SCHEDULE
will give it in formatted minutes and return 00:07:00

SELECT TIME_TO_MIN(TIMEDIFF(ETA,STA)) FROM SCHEDULE
gives 420

(7 * 60 seconds = 420)