# Convert day-hour-minute-seconds in minutes in SQL

Tags: date

I am trying to convert day-hour-minute-seconds into minute.
Three different examples would be

1 day 02:55:00
12 days 03:40:16
130 days 05:15:40

Thanks

Comment: Handling time calculations is a quite complex task. Is using a library an option? For time zones using DST days might have varying lenghts, e.g. 25h.

Comment: This job is to be done in SQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating time difference between 2 dates in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636599/calculating-time-difference-between-2-dates-in-minutes)